# Can a Super-intelligence rewrite the laws of physics?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, artificial-intelligence

An intelligence explosion is triggered by a combination of instructions to an AI to improve itself to make its algorithms more efficient/intelligent by consuming lesser resources to function every generation thus optimizing the intelligence per resource consumed ratio.

Leading up to millions of [black hole computers](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/black-hole-computers-2007-04/) networked via [E-R bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) to solve the distance problem (the higher intelligence might come up with a better solution).

Will that Super-intelligence be able to rewrite/modify the source code (laws of physics) of the universe?

Comment: What is the source code of the universe? The universe is not a computer program as far as  we know

Comment: @Raditz_35 clarified in edit

Comment: Please be more specific. What are the laws of physics? The idea of laws of physics is a result of the dogmatic approach in which they are taught. As far as I know there isn't a unified theory yet? Care to give one example. Which "law" would change into What law?

Comment: @Raditz_35 The limit on the amount of matter available in the universe is a bottleneck/hard limit. The ASI will have to rewrite the limiting laws in a clever way to allow for further expansion of intelligence. Of course, I doubt we humans can figure out that solution. But does the very statement of manipulating physical laws feasible or is it just a casual assumption that we make?

Comment: If it can travel faster than the universe expands, I'd argue the problem is already solved. This expands the observable universe, that means creating more matter.

Comment: @Raditz_35 But its more interested in achieving unlimited intelligence expansion without unnecessarily gobbling up all the matter the universe can provide.

Comment: Well, never mind me trying to answer the question in the comments, not the place, I sometimes forget. So you should ask first which "laws" exactly do limit the amount of available mass? Or are you asking how to create mass out of nothing? I still think you should specify exactly what you want your computer to do/accomplish.

Comment: What *is*   a   source  code   of   the  universe,  in your  world?   How  do you use black  holes  for computing?  How can it have a definitive answer when your  question is just a series of really big handwavess?

Comment: @Mołot I've added explanatory links. You can do a bit more research yourself to understand concepts like black hole computers more thoroughly.

Comment: It is customary here to wait 24 hours before accepting answer. That way people from all time zones have a chance to attempt to answer your question.

Comment: @Mołot Alright.

Comment: This is the plot of the [Heechee Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee) from Frederik Pohl.

Comment: So far no BSOD, so at least the Universe is not based on Windows...

Answer (score 12):

No. The universe does not "follow" any laws of physics, there is no source code to be rewritten. No "decisions" are made as in a computer program.

Humans have observed matter and deduced, for themselves, patterns of how matter behaves. Then humans captured a description of these patterns using mathematics to describe them.

However, the universe does not care how it is described, it is not consulting a rule book, it is not executing code to decide what to do or how to behave, electromagnetic repulsion is what it is, everywhere it is, there is no master rule somewhere that "governs" it, no master variable to change.

The universe is a thing. We can write a very detailed description of how it works, what you **think** are rules of the universe are all just ***predicting what will happen,*** under various circumstances, they are not ***determining*** what will happen. What determines what will happen, and what we are describing, is inherent in the energy, gravity and configuration of mass at every point in space.

We don't have a good description about how all that works, modern physics is incomplete and riddled with a dozen major problems. But whatever they are, no matter how smart we are or an AI can possibly become, it cannot change every particle in the universe just by ***knowing*** something. It might develop a better understanding of the laws of physics, that it could then exploit to do something we humans did not think possible, but that would not be rewriting them.

Comment: Those first three paragraphs are a perfect description of one of the fundamental misunderstandings of science. +1

Comment: Agreed. The universe does not follow laws in the same way that humans follow laws. The laws of physics are what we create (and sometimes rewrite) to help us understand the way the universe behaves, but that behaviour is neither conscious nor subject to a higher legislative authority.

Answer (score 4):

### Your computer is inside the universe, so no

**If your computer changes a law of physics that it uses then the computer no longer works**

Unless your AI can exist outside of a physics (and needing all those 'black-hole computers' and 'E-R' bridges, I'm guessing not) then the processes involved would all rely on physics, on the very things it would change. Any change in gravity would effect your black hole computers so you can't touch that or the computer won't work. Same goes for any physical process your computer uses...and I'd be willing to bet that leaves all *laws* of physics untouchable.

This is a story though, if you're inventing black hole computers and handwaving stability whilst connecting them with E-R bridges then you aren't really that fussed about what our universe says you *can* do. So go ahead, its your story.

(If your whole universe is, itself, a computer simulation, then maybe things can change).

Comment: He's    using  data  from inside a black  hole. What stops  him  from altering data outside  of  the  Universe,then?

Comment: @Mołot How does he access the data outside of the universe? Also, once he changes the laws of physics its likely everything involved in his super-intelligence's computation will be wrong and no longer work.

Comment: *"How does he access the data outside of the universe?"* - When he can get data from black hole, such borders are already handwaved  and   your question is   void.

Comment: @Mołot When "can X do Y" is asked more handwaving is hardly an answer though. Sure, if we say "Yes, your computer handwaves itself out of the universe" then we can start making up an ability to change the laws of physics but at that point every answer is as good as the next.

Comment: Of course it is not an answer. But saying "no" when   all the reasons preventing it seems to be already handwaved anyway also hardly is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

## It depends.

Most important: **can** the laws of physics be rewritten? For if they *cannot*, there's nothing more to be said.

If they *can* be rewritten, the superintelligence *may* deduce in which circumstances and to what extent they might be. Those circumstances might still well be impossible, the problem insoluble.

> [The Cosmic AC said, "NO PROBLEM IS INSOLUBLE IN ALL CONCEIVABLE CIRCUMSTANCES."](http://multivax.com/last_question.html)

It might be the case that you cannot do anything *to* the Universe from *inside* the Universe. Or any change to the laws that allow the superintelligence to *be* would disrupt that same superintelligence.

On the other hand, a superintelligence could e.g. discover that [the Universe is actually a simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis), deduce the underlying mechanisms and devise experiments to tease out their structure and algorithms, and finally locate some [*exploit*](https://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2618) in the simulation code. From there, the superintelligence could find a way of gaining root access on the host universe (this might be recursive) and rewrite the relevant parts of its own universe's source code.

Answer (score 1):

Very handwavy idea (and based, no doubt on a fundamental misunderstanding of quantum physics in our era), but quantum physics has a fundamental premise that wave functions "collapse" in the presence of an observer. Taken to its extreme, things do/do not exist unless or until someone or something observes it. This is the idea behind the [Schrodinger's cat](https://infogalactic.com/info/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) thought experiment.

[image]

*Many people believe Schrodinger simply did not want to empty the litter box*

If this understanding of quantum physics is true, then the idea of a super intelligence fundamentally modifying the laws of physics might be done by calculating the probability of a certain event happening, then setting the AI to "observe" closely. The concept might be called "looking for the preferred outcome", and involve using trillions of sensors and an "observer" primed to see a particular outcome.

There are two objections to this idea:

1. By only seeing what you "want" to see, you may simply be indulging in wishful thinking. This has led to rather embarrassing or dubious outcomes in the world of science, some examples being "[Polywater](https://infogalactic.com/info/Polywater)", "[Cold Fusion](https://infogalactic.com/info/Cold_fusion)" and [Lysenkoism](https://infogalactic.com/info/Lysenkoism).
2. If it works, it upsets the conditions of the "real world". If you are using computers based on certain physical principles (i.e. storing information on the ergosphere of a black hole like an enormous hard drive), then changing the underlying physics might cause the black holes to violently evaporate in a cloud of Hawking radiation, or other equally undesirable effects. This idea has been referred to as the "[Six Numbers](https://infogalactic.com/info/Dimensionless_physical_constant#Martin_Rees.27s_Six_Numbers)", and changing them could theoretically prevent the formation of stars, the inability of chemical reactions to take place and so on. There is no current theory which explains the existence of the "Six numbers" (or other physical constants) or why they have certain values, so changing them (if it is even possible) could literally be [apocalyptic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ApocalypseHow)

Answer (score -1):

**No, but** it might not need to.

Physical laws are beholden to nothing and no-one. They simply are. That said, our understanding of physics is incomplete and imperfect. A super intelligence may not be able to change then but might be able to utilize undiscovered laws and properties yet unknown to any but itself.

To use a game analogy, the core rules stay the same, but only the super intelligence has the expansion and its game breaking options.

Comment: You see, now you're going to have to address the fact that "[hidden variable theories](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_variable_theory)" have been ruled out following the work of Bell and Bohm.